# How to import very large geojson files into neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, geojson

### Background of problem

---

I'm currently building an app that models various geographic features (roads, towns, highways, etc.) in a graph database. The geographic data is all in GeoJSON format.

There is no **LOAD JSON** function in the cypher language, so loading JSON files requires passing the fully parsed JavaScript object as a parameter and using **UNWIND** to access arrayed properties and objects to create nodes. (This guide helped me out a lot to get started: [Loading JSON in neo4j](https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-load-json-from-url/)). Since GeoJSON is just a spec built on JSON conventions, the load JSON method works great for reasonably sized files.

However, **geographic data files can be massive**. Some of the files I'm trying to import range from 100 features to 200,000 features.

The problem I'm running into is that with these very large files, **the query will not MERGE any nodes in the database until it has completely processed the file**. For large files, **this often exceeds the 3600s timeout limit** set in neo4j. So I end up waiting for an hour to find out that I have no new data in my database.

I know that with some data, the [current recommendation is to convert it to CSV and then use the optimization of LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/blog/import-10m-stack-overflow-questions/). However, I don't believe it is easy to condense GeoJSON into CSV.

### Primary Question

---

Is it possible to send the data from a very large JSON/GeoJSON file over in smaller batches so that neo4j will commit the data intermittently?

### Current Approach

---

To import my data, I built a simple Express app that connects to my neo4j database via the bolt protocol (using official binary JS drivers). My GeoJSON files all have a well known text (WKT) property for each feature so that I can make use of neo4j-spatial.

Here's an example of the code I would use to import a set of road data:

```
session.run("WITH {json} as data UNWIND data.features as features MERGE (r:Road {wkt:features.properties.wkt})", {json: jsonObject})
  .then(function (result) {
    var records = [];
    result.records.forEach((value) => {
      records.push(value);
    });
    console.log("query completed");
    session.close();
    driver.close();
    return records;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    // Close out the session objects
    session.close();
    driver.close();
  });
```

As you can see I'm passing in the entire parsed GeoJSON object as a parameter in my cypher query. Is there a better way to do this with very large files to avoid the timeout issue I'm experiencing?

Comment: neo4j now supports loading json with the help of apoc plugin https://neo4j.com/blog/intro-user-defined-procedures-apoc/

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be helpful here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59617967/1967693

---

[apoc.load.jsonArray()](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/overview/apoc.load/apoc.load.jsonArray/) will stream the values of the given JSON file. This can then be used as data source for batching via [apoc.periodic.iterate](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/).

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "CALL apoc.load.json('https://dummyjson.com/products', '$.features') YIELD value AS features",
  "UNWIND features as feature MERGE (r:Road {wkt:feature.properties.wkt})",
  {batchSize:1000, parallel:true}
)
```